# JOIN Google PLAY store data with Android Device Catalog

Tags: android, google-play

When I download Google PLAY store review reports, there is a Device column that contains device labels, such as:

```
fortunave3g
zeroflteusc
ZTE_Blade_A475
mlv5
j1acevelte
coreprimelte
gt58lte
D2306
```

I can lookup these Device labels manually within the PLAY store's Device catalog to learn about each device's RAM, screen size, SoC, CPU, OpenGL version, etc.

How can I perform this search (or JOIN operation) *programmatically*? With a single table that merged device data with report data I could pinpoint relationships between, for example, poor reviews and low memory, or crashes and opengl 2.0

I see no solution here in the Google PLAY Developer API.
[Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/)

I found a list of supported devices that includes the device label, but it does not contain the device data other than manufacturer, Marketing Name, and Model.
[Google PLAY Help - Supported Devices](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1727131?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of doing this at the moment.

Comment: We're working on it Nick. Hopefully we'll have an update by next week. It may not be 100% ToS-compliant, but we found the raw data.

Comment: If possible, please provide an answer to your own question indicating how this was done, and if this still works today.